# Why would it be that a laptop's HDMI port for an external monitor only works from within Windows, and not in the UEFI/BIOS?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Why would it be that a laptop's HDMI  port for an external monitor only works from within Windows, and not in the UEFI/BIOS?

i.e. If I go to the laptop's UEFI/BIOS you see the little HDMI screen on the right is blank.

[image]

But while the laptop starts going into Windows, then it wakes up / the screen gets the signal.

[image]

The laptop is old, it's a Samsung NP350V5C from maybe 2012. It does have a VGA port too. A VGA monitor shows the UEFI/BIOS.

The screen is designed for Raspberry Pis, particularly a Raspberry Pi with an HDMI connector eg Raspberry Pi 4, but i've plugged the screen into a laptop instead. It's a 5" screen made by "Jun-Saxifragelec".  I don't know if it being a portable monitor makes a difference.. or if any HDMI monitor would operate like that with that laptop.

The BIOS/UEFI doesn't have an option of which port to send the graphics out of.

I'm wondering if the issue is computer end (so a standard HDMI screen would be fine), or is the HDMI screen side of things, so if the screen is non-standard in some way.

Comment: It’s not that unusual that only a single display work’s within UEFI. Even on my desktop only a single display works over DisplayPort and HDMI

Comment: I'm only using one external display.  And it's that when you plug the screen into HDMI then it only starts running within Windows.   I wonder if, were it a UEFI with an option to change between HDMI and VGA , then would the VGA only start when going into Windows.

Comment: Your device has 2 displays the external one and the built-in display.

Comment: If I have two external displays connected,(that makes three displays total counting the built in one),  then are you suggesting that even from within Windows, only one external display would work? (Hence your statement that the device has 2 displays - including the built in one)

Comment: I have 2 external displays on all my devices.  When I boot the majority of my machines, only one of those displays will display the UEFI boot logo and/or UEFI, thus my statement that only a single display working is not unusual.